# Update an uneditable input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two objects X and Y. They share master detail relationship. X is the master object and Y the detail object. Y object has a field called currency shown on the page and has a button whose function is to add row of new Object Y with currency field. So if the user wants more detail objects then he can click as many times and create more Y object with many input field of currency. Now my problem is that I have an input field in Object X on VF page which calculates the total of the currency which user inputs. If there is one row or many rows the total of al currency is shown in the total amount box. I am stuck as I have to use Jquery or javascript on the front end to update the final amount box as the user is entering the values in the currency field. Updating of total amount field and entering of the currency has to be done simultaneously. Plus the total amount field is uneditable.

```
<apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Amount</apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!payment.TotalAmount__c}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>
<apex:commandLink value="Add currency Row" action="{!RowMultiple}" immediate="true"
                                          reRender="PayDateSection">
                            <apex:param assignTo="{!rowId}" value="{!paymentDetails.name}" name="demo"/>
                        </apex:commandLink>

 <apex:column>
                        <apex:facet name="header">Currency</apex:facet>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Currency.Amount__c}" required="true"/>
                    </apex:column>
```

I have to update the total amount to be sum of all the currency amount in Currency detail object and also updating has to be done simultaneously.

Comment: You have Y is a child of X. and You have a field called Amount in Y and you want to get sum of all amounts in a field of X. If my understanding is correct, then you can use roll-up summary field to update the total amount in X. In the VF page, render the Total Amount block as and when a new currency record is added in Y object.

Comment: Roll up summary is not to be used plus when the user enters the currency then as the user is entering it the amount field has to be updated by adding the currency which user is entering. All this using frontend javascript and jquery. I need something to update it on the go when the user is entering the currency value. that is the goal so that the customer can see the total amount while he inputs the currency on the vf page

Comment: So where are you stuck at? I don't see what you've tried that isn't working for you. It seems like this could also be done in your controller. Are you asking us to write JS/jQuery for you?

Comment: How can this be done using the controller?? Yes I tried few things but they are not working I am new to salesforce so want some help on this. thanks